# textFieldDidEndEditing alternative

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

Hi I am using to following code to keep 2 `UIButtons` disabled until there is data in four `UITextField`s

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


if (([brand.text length] >0) && ([qty.text length] >0) && ([size.text length] >0) && ([price.text length] >0)) {
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:YES];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:YES];

}
if (([brand.text length] ==0) || ([qty.text length] ==0) || ([size.text length] ==0) || ([price.text length] ==0)){

    [calcOneButton setEnabled:NO];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:NO];
}

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

int ebtl = [brand.text length];
int eqtl = [qty.text length];
int estl = [size.text length];
int eptl = [price.text length];
NSLog(@"ebtl = %d eqtl = %d estl = %d eptl = %d",ebtl, eqtl, estl, eptl); 

if (([brand.text length] ==0) || ([qty.text length] ==0) || ([size.text length] ==0) || ([price.text length] ==0)){
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:NO];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:NO];
}
if (([brand.text length] >0) && ([qty.text length] >0) && ([size.text length] >0) && ([price.text length] >0)) {
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:YES];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

}

My problem is that `textFieldDidEndEditing` isn't called until the user taps away from the textField. this creates the need to tap the screen then the button is there a way to avoid this, so the button will be enabled immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button will become active only when the user taps away from textField. If you are using the normal keyboard which pops up, use the DONE button on the keyboard to get rid of the keyboard, and then write an IBAction when the keyboard resigns itself, and then enable your buttons.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder]; //enable your buttons after this
return 1;
}
```

or use an IBAction:

```
-(IBAction) textFieldFinishedDone: (id) sender; // enable your buttons after this
```

The buttons must get active only when ALL textFields are filled right ? You can do this. 
Comment out both the functions you have written above. Use the IBAction and whenever you press the DONE and resign the keyboard , check all textFields for their status. Using an if-else block, make your buttons appear when all textFields are done.

Comment: I'm only using the normal keyboard on one of the fields, the other 3 are all the number keypad.
Can I link an action to Editing Changed or Value changed in the fields events properties?

Comment: Use this tutorial to create a Return key for Number Keypad. http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Comment: Sorry I did not read your question properly; Buttons must get active when ALL textFields are completed right ??

Comment: yes that is right, I have linked this to an action now using the event editing cahnged property of the textfield. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For the best user experience, I would suggest performing the behavior in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` always returning YES.

also, the logic in the methods above is redundant,
preferred implementation:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  if (([brand.text length] >0) && 
      ([qty.text length] >0) && 
      ([size.text length] >0) && 
      ([price.text length] >0)) {
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:YES];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:YES];
  } else {
    [calcOneButton setEnabled:NO];
    [calcTwoButton setEnabled:NO];
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for responding, I already have a lot going on under `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` so I have now linked to an action using the event editing changed property.